# Как на python задать шанс выпадения?

Tags: python

например -

```
import random

chance = random.randint(1,100)

if chance == (шанс выпадения от 1 до 50):
    print("1, 50")

if chance == (шанс выпадения от 51 до 95):
    print("51, 95")

if chance == (шанс выпадения 96 до 100):
    print("96, 100")
```

В этих промежутках должен быть шанс выпадения. Как его сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`random.randint(x, y)` возвращает псевдослучайное число, равномерно распределённое на интервале `[x; y]`. Значит, для нахождения вероятности выпадения числа в определённом интервале достаточно взять отношение длины этого интервала к длине всего интервала.

То есть шанс выпадения для `[1; 50]` есть `50 / 100 = 0.5`, для `[51; 95]` — `0.45`, для `[96; 100]` — `0.05`.

```py
def chance(x, y):
    return (y - x + 1) / 100
```